# React ui material show snackbar with a router change

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to show a snackbar if 
the request is successful so I implement this
simple code

```
AuthService.signup(formData)
        .then((_) => {
          setOpen(true);
          history.push("/auth/login");
        })
        .catch((_) => {
          setError(true);
        })
        .finally(() => {
          setLoading(false);
        });
```

but I don't see any snackbar :(
if I get rid of history.push("/auth/login");
the snackbar is showed normally

Can you give me an example
how to use it
with a change of route, please?

Comment: snackbar should be implemented as an independent component from signup

Comment: Sorry but I dont see the point can you give me a simple example?

Comment: @user3887366 Did you find a solution?